# Make Firefox prompt me to close even when using session saving?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

It appears that Firefox 3.5 has a "feature" where if you have it set to restore your tabs on restart, it doesn't prompt you for confirmation when you close it (see [this page](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/06/19/firefox-3-doesnt-prompt-or-warn-to-confirm-when-closing-multiple-tabs-as-warning-not-working/) for more background).  However, I'd like it to both save my state **and** prompt me when I (generally accidentally) close it.

Is there a way to override this behavior to have it prompt me anyways?  I'd be happy to install an add-on if there was one that would solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `about:config`.
Find the setting named `browser.tabs.warnOnClose` and set it to "true" (double-click the name to toggle between "true" and "false").

Comment: This flag is set to true.  The problem is that when you tell Firefox to restore your session on restart (browser.startup.page == 3), it ignores the browser.tabs.warnOnClose flag and doesn't prompt you.

Comment: It works fine for me: Firefox is set to restore the session on restart AND it prompts me when I close the browser.

Comment: What version/OS are you on?  I'm on 3.6b5 and OS X 10.5.

Comment: FF 3.6b5 on Windows 7 Ultimate